# How to build NodeJS in XCode IDE?

Tags: xcode, macos, node.js

How can I build NodeJS within the XCode IDE as a project? NodeJS build instructions say that it should be built with:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However I wish to build within the XCode IDE.

What I really want to do is embed NodeJS within my application, so I think if I can build NodeJS within XCode then I can just adjust it to add my application once I have NodeJS building and running.

I made some progress I think by getting V8 to compile in XCode, now I am trying to add NodeJS to the V8 project.

Comment: I know it does not 'helps' but could you express the reason of trying to build it using XCode IDE?

Comment: Phil, have you ever figured that out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run `./configure --xcode` in node repository root and you will get `node.xcodeproj` file you want.

Answer (score 2):

As of this commit in Node.js - https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/20328 one must do -

```
./configure -- -f xcode
```